# how to Search profile type in drupal 7

Tags: users

I created a profile type for users to upload their data using fields and I want other users (registered or anonymous) to have access to a search form and they can search for anything on any user's profile (name, jobtype, gender, etc) [image: user data field collection]

if a another user searches for a string in job search, the entire information should be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. This can be done by "[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)". Use a form as user profile, and set limit 1 form per user in "Form settings". Then use "[Permission per webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_per_webform)" to make this form access webform results for all user. To display in search, it can simply be done by [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

---

Update: another idea I found is to use "[View profiles permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_profiles_perms)". This module provides permission to view user profiles depending on what roles the profile requested to be viewed.